# Numpy savez / load thousands of arrays, but not in one step

Tags: python, arrays, serialization, numpy

I would like to store approx 4000 numpy arrays (of 1.5 MB each) in a serialized uncompressed file (approx 6 GB of data). Here is an example with 2 small arrays :

```
import numpy
d1 = { 'array1' : numpy.array([1,2,3,4]), 'array2': numpy.array([5,4,3,2]) }
numpy.savez('myarrays', **d1)

d2 = numpy.load('myarrays.npz')
for k in d2:
    print d2[k]
```

It works, but I would like to do the same thing **not in a single step** :

- When saving, I would like to be able to save 10 arrays, then do some other task (than may use some seconds), then write 100 other arrays, then do something else, then write some other 50 arrays, etc.
- When loading : *idem*, I would like to be able to load some arrays, then do some other task, then continue the loading.

**How to do with this `numpy.savez` /  `numpy.load` ?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't think you can do this with np.savez. This, however, is the perfect use-case for hdf5. See either:

http://www.h5py.org

or

http://www.pytables.org

As an example of how to do this in h5py:

```
h5f = h5py.File('test.h5', 'w')
h5f.create_dataset('array1', data=np.array([1,2,3,4]))
h5f.create_dataset('array2', data=np.array([5,4,3,2]))
h5f.close()

# Now open it back up and read data
h5f = h5py.File('test.h5', 'r')
a = h5f['array1'][:] 
b = h5f['array2'][:]
h5f.close()
print a
print b
# [1 2 3 4]
# [5 4 3 2]
```

And of course there are more sophisticated ways of doing this, organizing arrays via groups, adding metadata, pre-allocating space in the hdf5 file and then filling it later, etc.

Comment: Great! I tried h5py, and writing is rather straightforward with createdataset, but do you have an example of how to read back an array?

Comment: Given `a = h5f['array1']`, `a` is just a reference to the data set. `a` does not actually pull the data into memory. On the other hand `a = h5f['array1'][:]` actually gets the data out of the h5 file and loads it into the variable `a`. The notation means get a slice of the data containing all elements. You could also use `[...]` or you could get a subset using something like `[1:3]`.

Comment: Thanks for this useful information!
`a = h5f['array1']` is like a pointer, and `a = h5f['array1'][:]` actually retrieves the data? Is it a general rule that `[:]` does a real copy into memory ?

Comment: Consider: `a = np.arange(100); b = a[:]; np.may_share_memory(a,b)` returns `True`, so in numpy there is no guarantee of a copy with that notation, since the above gives you a view.

Comment: I'm currently doing some profiling tests, and I can't get coherent results (because I imagine that Windows does some caching into memory) : I get values like 20 seconds, 27 seconds or even 38 seconds when loading a 2 GB random numpy array...

How does `h5py` loading time compare to `numpy.load` about speed efficiency ?

Comment: I added a question about how to do a good benchmarking/comparison of `h5py.create_dataset` and `numpy.save` : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22363061/how-to-get-consistent-results-when-compare-speed-of-numpy-save-and-h5py

Answer (score 1):

`savez` in the current numpy is just writing the arrays to temp files with `numpy.save`, and then adds them to a zip file (with or without compression).

If you're not using compression, you might as well skip step 2 and just save your arrays one by one, and keep all 4000 of them in a single folder.

Comment: I was able, using an 'archive manager' to add an `.npy` file (array) to an `.npz` (and load it).  So saving multiple `.npz', and merging them can be done (at worse it will involve extracting files to a temp dir).